# Can I query a different AD domain with the default Win7 install?

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, domain, command-line-arguments, query

**Background**

I work in an Enterprise where our Active Directory is locked down pretty tight and only Info Security has access to administer changes. I'm using a standard `Win7 Enterprise x64 Service Pack 1` PC with `UAC` locked down fairly tight and I do not have any special LDAP querying tools on my desktop. I am a local admin on my PC but, if possible, I'd like to avoid changes to my desktop environment as our Security team gets prickly about that sort of thing.

**Problem**

I frequently use `NET GROUP /DOMAIN [groupname]` and `NET USER /DOMAIN [username]` through the command prompt to query group access on our primary domain. I've recently come across a situation where I need to check group membership on a different test domain but (unless I'm mistaken) it appears that these command only work on the active domain. I do have an account and a password on this other domain but I have no idea how to query it.

**Question**

Is there an easy way for me as an end user without special admin tools and with the basic Windows setup to query a different domain than the one I am currently on? I looked up the TechNet articles on [`Net Group`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754051.aspx) and [`Net User`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865.aspx) but I didn't see how I could switch the target domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `dsquery group` with the `-Server` parameter.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't appear dsquery comes standard with Win7 Enterprise Install. I get a 'is not recognized as an external or internal command error when I try and run this'.